# gae running smoothly but not capable of retrieving data using html and client.js

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

I am running into an issue where all google app endpoints are running smoothly. No issue at getting, updating or deleting entries while using the API explorer.

I am running into issue when trying to mesh all this together in an html file.
Updates and deletes work fine... Only get/list methods are returning no record.

Any idea what the issue is? What is best to troubleshoot this kind of issue?

Thanks.

**test.java**

```
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.*;

@Entity
@Index
public class Test {

@Id Long number;
Long number2;

public Test(){

}

public Test(Long number, Long number2){
    this.number = number;
    this.number2 = number2;
}
public Test(Long number2){
    this.number2 = number2;
}

public Long getNumber2() {
    return number2;
}

public void setNumber2(Long number2) {
    this.number2 = number2;
}

public Long getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setNumber(Long number) {
    this.number = number;
}
```

}

**test.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <form>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="insert" value="2"><br><br>
            <button type="submit" id="getTestButton" onclick="getTest()" disabled>Get</button>
        </div>

    </form>

    <p id="result"></p>
    <hr>
</div>
<!--
 Load the Google APIs Client Library for JavaScript
 More info here : https://developers.google.com/api-client-    library/javascript/reference/referencedocs
-->
<script type="text/javascript">
function init() {
    gapi.client.load('testEndpoint', 'v1', enableButton, 'http://localhost:8080/_ah/api');

    document.getElementById('getTestButton').onclick = function() {
        getTest();
    }
}

function enableButton() {
    console.log("enabling button");
    getTestButton.disabled = false;
}

function getTest() {
    console.log("entering getTest function");

    var features = {};
    features.number2 = document.getElementById("insert").value;

    console.log(features);

    var req = gapi.client.testEndpoint.getTest(features);

    req.execute(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = data.number + " " + data.number2;
    });
}
</script>

<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

TestEndpoint.java

```
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Api;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiMethod;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiNamespace;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.inject.Named;
import com.googlecode.objectify.cmd.Query;

import static com.Backend.OfyService.ofy;

/** An endpoint class we are exposing */
@Api(name = "testEndpoint", version = "v1", namespace = @ApiNamespace(ownerDomain =    "Backend.com", ownerName = "Backend.com", packagePath=""))
public class TestEndpoint {

    // Make sure to add this endpoint to your web.xml file if this is a web application.

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(TestEndpoint.class.getName());

    /**
     * This method gets the <code>Test</code> object associated with the specified    <code>id</code>.
     * @param id The id of the object to be returned.
     * @return The <code>Test</code> associated with <code>id</code>.
     */
    @ApiMethod(name = "getTest")
    public Test getTest(@Named("number2") Long number2) {
        // Implement this function
        LOG.info("***GetTest***NUMBER=" + number2);
        Test t = new Test(1L, 2L);

        //t = ofy().load().type(Test.class).filter("number2", number2).first().now();

        LOG.info("t.getNumber()==> " + t.getNumber().toString());
        LOG.info("Calling getTest method");

        return t;
    }
}
```

Comment: Might want to add the google-cloud-endpoints tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems legit to me. To isolate the cause of the error, I would suggest to do the following :

1. Test your `getTest` endpoint method through the API explorer, located at `http://yourAppAddress/_ah/api/explorer` . If it works you know the issue is in your client code.
2. If it did not work, then the issue is either with the code inside `getTest` or with the way you use endpoints (or with endpoints itself). To check this, create a pure Java servlet that will call the `getTest()` method directly, and log the result. If it works you know the issue is either on the way you use endpoints or on endpoints itself.

Sorry I don't have an immediate answer to your question.

EDIT : Since you tell me that the API Explorer test works, I checked your javascript code and there's something weird : you try to get `resp.items.length` in the callback. But your endpoint method only returns a `Test` entity, so there are no `items` attribute.

Can you try this code ?

```
gapi.client.testEndpoint.getTest(requestData).execute(function(resp) {
       console.log(resp);
});
```

EDIT 2 : So you've found the cause of the issue by yourself : you cannot call the endpoints method before the API client is loaded. Since your method is called by an `onClick` event, probably on a button, you must do the following :

- By default, disable the button
- In the `gapi.client.load` 's callback, enable the button

That way you will be sure to only click on the button when the Google service is initialized.

EDIT 3 : It is actually a problem in your html. You have a submit button, which makes Chrome reload the page. Every time you click the button the page reloads and you never see the result of your endpoint query.

This HTML file works for me on the dev server :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div>

    <div>
        <input type="text" id="insert" value="2"><br><br>
        <button id="getTestButton" onclick="getTest()" disabled>Get</button>
    </div>


    <p id="result"></p>
    <hr>
</div>
<!--
 Load the Google APIs Client Library for JavaScript
 More info here : https://developers.google.com/api-client-    library/javascript/reference/referencedocs
-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    function init() {
        gapi.client.load('testEndpoint', 'v1', enableButton, '/_ah/api');

        document.getElementById('getTestButton').onclick = function () {
            getTest();
        }
    }

    function enableButton() {
        console.log("enabling button");
        getTestButton.disabled = false;
    }

    function getTest() {
        console.log("entering getTest function");

        var features = {};
        features.number2 = document.getElementById("insert").value;

        console.log(features);

        var req = gapi.client.testEndpoint.getTest(features);

        req.execute(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = data.number + " " + data.number2;
        });
    }
</script>

<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Truly appreciate as I've been running with this issue for some few days now. To answer your question, the expected result is properly returned by this endpoint/method. What would make this test while using a servlet different than using the api explorer? Again, appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: If you re-read my answer, you'll see that the servlet test is only useful if the api explorer test did not work.

I've edited my answer with a guess on your issue.

Comment: I modified the script and added logging of the response to the console. Nothing is showing up.

Comment: Can you check the network communication ? If you're using Chrome it is in the dev tools. The Endpoints calls are made to the /_ah/api/rpc URL

Comment: Looks like something is being transferred... Anything special will should look into?

Comment: Well you should be able to see the content of the answer, and see if you indeed see the test entity you're expecting. Here's an example http://screencast.com/t/P0nn7y8gqF . By the way are you testing on the local dev server or on an app deployed on App Engine ?

Comment: From what I can see we can find out the method called by the javascript (getTest) (edited original question with log from the response tab as well). The result refers to the object (t) so it appears to me like everything is good. Testing is currently performed on my local dev server.

Comment: What you've found in the network tab is the rcp discovery request, when the API client asks the servers which methods are available. But then it calls the `getTest()` method in another RPC call, that's what you should be looking for. Are you sure your `getTest()` method is called at some point ?

Comment: I do not see any other RPC call under the 'network/response' tab. However, I have looked at some other calls that are running fine (e.g. insert) and  I do not see any other RPC call either.... Thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure your `getTest()` method is executed in your javascript code ? Can you add some logging to make sure of this ?

Comment: I added some logging right before and after the gapi.client call. The log just before shows up in the javascript console, I can see traces on the endpoint side along with the object being returned. However, the log right after the gapi.client call does not right anything to the console.

Comment: By "after" do you mean in the callback or after the call to `getText()` ? If there's nothing after the call to `getText()` it's definitely a bug of the Endpoints client. Can you try on appspot.com ?

Comment: Log trace before and after the gapi.client call. I also added a trace in the endpoint method. I'll give it a try on appspot.com later and will let you know.

Comment: I am still trying to do this test. However, I am experimenting other issues that seem to be related to Objectify and Google Data store. Not sure why but the code is running ok locally but not on GAEs. More to come. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25703994/google-app-engine-fails-using-app-engineupdate-and-app-cfg-sh-different-errors

Comment: I was able to upload to appspot.com with no much issue. Creation of the entity worked ok. However, it is still impossible to retrieve information from this very simple entity. Additional logging within the javascript did not help much as it does not seem to go beyond the gapi.client.getTest call. What should I do next to troubleshoot and hopefully fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: I think that's a bug. If you have a support contract with App Engine, contact them directly. Otherwise file a defect report here : https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/FilingIssues?tm=3

Comment: I have been able for this to work partially... It works whenever calling the getTest function as a call back of the gapi.client.load function. However this does not work on the 'on click'...?

Comment: Ah ok, so that's because you call the endpoint method before the endpoint API is loaded. I have added an "EDIT 2" to my answer, but basically you need to wait for the endpoint API to be loaded before starting calling it.

Comment: I thought we were on something.... But it does not work still. I added a callback function to enable the button on the gapi.load but still experimenting same behavior. I've also slightly modified the endpoint code to have no interaction with the data store whatsoever. All I am doing is to instantiate a new 'Test' object and return it to the html. Again, it does work when called on the 'gapi.load' callback function but not while using the html button.

Comment: At this point could you provide a complete example, client+server, that fails ?

Comment: I think it's just a form submission problem, can you try with the html I have put in my answer ?

Comment: Good news. It is finally working as expected. On a second thought the web browser was probably mixed up between the request sent by the form on the one from the gapi library. Million thanks for your precious help!