# google app engine fails using app engine:update and app cfg.sh, different errors

Tags: google-app-engine

My questions is in two folds: issue with app engine:update and with the app cfg.sh.

I looked on the web and could not find any workaround or potential answer that could help me fixing this issue.

My application is working with not much issue locally. Time now to give it a shot on production and upload it to google app engine. At first I tried doing this by using the 'app engine:update' from gradle (I'm using Android Studio). The execution failed with the following error message: "toolkit not found: apple.awt.ctoolkit. Why is this toolkit required and where can we find it?

While searching on the internet there were suggestions to use the appcfg.sh script to upload the application. It seemed to work at first until it asked for email and password. I used the exact same email/password I use to connect to goole-appengine and for some reasons it does not work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few hours investigating this issue I found out what the issues were. First thing, my account was compromised and received an email from Google. All I had is to confirm that was me trying to upload application to GAE. Secondly, my primary email address linked to my Google account belongs to another ISP. There is a security feature to disable and for security being a bit more loose. Creating a gmail account did the trick.